# Execute method of objects that are in array

Tags: c#, arrays, object, methods

I have a bunch of objects in c# that have the method `finalPrice()` in common. I put them all in an array.

I want to use a `foreach` so I can execute `finalPrice()` on each one.

`precioBase` is the atribute I want to show in every iteration, but first i have to use `finalPrice()` on every object of the array (every "articulo").

Code:

```
Electrodomestico articulo1 = new Electrodomestico(1000, 5,'F',"azul");
Electrodomestico articulo2 = new Electrodomestico();
Electrodomestico articulo3 = new Electrodomestico(1600, 60);         
Electrodomestico articulo4 = new Electrodomestico(3000, 90, 'J');           
Electrodomestico articulo5 = new Electrodomestico(1000, 5, 'F', "violeta");

Lavadora articulo6 = new Lavadora();
Lavadora articulo7 = new Lavadora(10, 600, 'A', "rojo", 50);

Television articulo8 = new Television();
Television articulo9 = new Television(20, 5000, 'D', "gris", true, 60);
Television articulo10 = new Television(10, 10000);

object[] electrodomestico = {articulo1,articulo2,articulo3,articulo4,articulo5,articulo6,articulo7,articulo8,articulo9,articulo10 };

foreach(double elarticulo in electrodomestico)
{

}
```

Comment: Please paste formatted and correct code. Your `foreach` statement is missing the opening bracket, for example. Your array is not how you instantiate arrays in C#, either. What types are `articuloX`? If you don't show a very basic amount of effort in crafting your question, you're unlikely to get very much help.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't speak english very well and didn't know how to tell what I'm looking for correctly. There are 3 classes in my program, A, B and C. both B and C inherit from A. I created objects of the three classes, they are called "articulos" and put them in an array. All of these objects have the method finalPrice() in common, so I want to use that method for every object in the array, regarless of them being from different classes

Comment: What i could interpret from this bit of code is that your articulo objects are just doubles . so you can use it like this 

     foreach(double precioBase in electrodomestico) {
         precioBase.finalPrice();
        }

Comment: It's not about English - it's about the code you've given us. It should at the very least compile, since your question isn't about compilation errors. Show us the actual code you're using at the moment.

Comment: added code, sorry for being a noob

Comment: Don't use `object[]` for collections, make a base type called `Product`, then make  `Electrodomestico`, `Television`, `Lavadora` derive from it, so that you can use a strongly-typed collection `List<Product>` to hold all your products.

Comment: You need to create an array of your Base type assuming it has the concrete (or abstract) `finalPrice` method on it.  An `object[]` isn't sufficient.

Comment: The code you posted isn't valid. It will fail in the `foreach` at runtime, because the objects in the array aren't of type `double`. Given that you are hard-coding the array elements anyway, why not just call the desired method there? E.g.: `double[] electrodomestico = {articulo1.finalPrice(),articulo2.finalPrice(),articulo3.finalPrice(),... };`. Other alternatives require use of the `dynamic` type (e.g. `dynamic[] electrodomestico = ...;` or making each type (`Electrodomestico`, `Lavadora`, and `Television`) inherit a common type (class or interface) where `finalPrice()` is declared.

Comment: There are already lots of Q&A on Stack Overflow covering these topics. Please research the basic language concepts useful for this type of task, and if you still have trouble, post a new question with a good [mcve] that shows clearly what _specifically_ you are having trouble understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Electrodomestico es currently the base class, so could I make a List<Electrodomestico> to hold them all, and then call the method on each one somehow? Is there a problem if there are objects of the class electrodomestico too?

Comment: If Electrodomestico is the base class for all the objects then List<Electrodomestico> will work. The function you want to call for each object must also be defined in Electrodomestico class.

Comment: It is amit, thanks! how should i add the 10 objects to the list, and then, how to call the method for all 10 of them?

Comment: just declare a variable List<Electrodomestico> Electrodomesticos = new Lis<Electrodomestico>(); then Use Electrodomesticos.Add(any object that inherit from Electrodomestico);

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully I don't get down voted for helping but here is a solution to your question. The classes you listed should all implement a common interface. Such as the one below:

```
interface ICommonPriceFunctions
{
    double FinalPrice();
}
```

That way the code knows that all classes that implement the `ICommonPriceFunctions` interface all have the `FinalPrice()` method. You will then need to modify your classes to implement the `ICommonPriceFunctions` interface and write code for the `FinalPrice()` method. Something like below:

```
class Electrodomestico : ICommonPriceFunctions
{
    public double FinalPrice()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Electrodomestico .FinalPrice()");
        return 0.0; // return whatever value you need
    }
}
```

You will need to do for ALL classes and modify the `FinalPrice()` method based on the class. Then its simply a matter of creating an array of type `ICommonPriceFunctions`, looping through the items and then calling the `FinalPrice()` method. Like below:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var electrodomestico = new Electrodomestico();
            var lavadora = new Lavadora();
            var television = new Television();
            var objects = new ICommonPriceFunctions[]{ electrodomestico, lavadora, television };
            foreach(var ob in objects){
                var finalPrice = ob.FinalPrice();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know I was thinking Save() it should have been finalPrice(). Mybad

Comment: You are able to edit your answer - you can change it to read `finalPrice` instead of `Save` :) - look at the bottom of the answer - `share edit delete flag`

Comment: Do people really downvote others who try to help? Thanks for the help, i will try this if the list does not work for me

Comment: OK I hopefully made the right edits. Hopefully you can use the code as a base to do what you need it to do

Comment: I voted you up. I think you analyzed the problem correctly. i.e. the different classes do not have a shared interface and he can't therefore run the method.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't able to access the fields or methods, because you've typed the array as an array of objects. You can write something like this:

```
var electrodomestico = new Electrodomestico[] { articulo1, articulo2, articulo3, articulo4, articulo5, articulo6, articulo7, articulo8, articulo9, articulo10 };
```

Which means you now have an array of `Electrodomestico`.

For your for-loop:

```
foreach(double elarticulo in electrodomestico)
```

You're saying each object is a double. That's incorrect - each object is a `LavaDora`, `Television`, etc. Since they all inherit from `Electrodomestico`, we need to write:

```
foreach(Electrodomestico elarticulo in electrodomestico)
```

However, since we have a typed array now, we don't need to specify it again (C# can work it out for us)

```
foreach(var elarticulo in electrodomestico)
```

I'm still unsure what you mean by this:

> precioBase is the atribute I want to show in every iteration, but first i have to use finalPrice() on every object of the array (every "articulo").

Whether that means you need to run `finalPrice()` to calculate the value, and then retrieve it via `precioBase`, or whether `finalPrice()` returns the value of `precioBase`.

I'll assumin `finalPrice()` gives us the value we want. In that case, we can write:

```
foreach(var elarticulo in electrodomestico)
{
    var finalPrice = elarticulo.finalPrice();
    Console.WriteLine(finalPrice);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the suspicion that all three types could extend a base type.
`finalPrice()` could be an abstract on this base type.

So then you could write something like:

```
mybase[] electrodomestico = {articulo1,articulo2,articulo3,articulo4,articulo5,articulo6,articulo7,articulo8,articulo9,articulo10 };

var finalPrice = (from o in electrodomestico select o.finalPrice()).Sum();
```